# innerHTML doesn't respect indentation

Tags: javascript, indentation

I have a code on the client side that receives some data through socket.io with a node.js backend. I receive some indented data (which is some code in string format). I can alert the code out and I see it is indented in the alert, but when I do `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = receivedData.indentedData` the data outputted in `myDiv` is not indented, but just in a single line.

Do you know a way to have the indentation respected in some string when filling an HTML element?

To be more precise I alert the data in this form:

```
class Motto {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Java rules!");
  }
}
```

But what I see in `myDiv` is this:

```
class Motto { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("Java rules!"); } }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, outputting code like this, you'll want to wrap it in `<pre>` and `<code>` tags.

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = "<pre><code>"+receivedData.indentedData+"</code></pre>";
```

That's what the StackOverflow markdown editor does for code snippets.

Answer (score 4):

`innerHTML` respects indentation. The problem is the way how HTML itself represents data: it displays all whitespace as a single space. Replacing `\n` with `<br>` is only a partial solution because tabs won't still be saved. Better use `#myDiv { white-space: pre; }` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\n` with `<br>`. As you may know, line breaks aren't displayed as such in HTML, but are treated as spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML =
    receivedData.indentedData.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

In HTML, line breaks are ignored, you have to use `<br>` for line breaks.